# Is value-at-risk methodology patented?

Tags: intellectual-property, united-states, finance

If a software provides calculation of [value-at-risk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_at_risk) based on some text book methods (say the one described by [John C. Hull](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_C._Hull)), does the publisher of the software become liable to any claims for violation of intellectual property?

A simple google search reveals - https://patents.google.com/patent/US7356504B2/en but I cannot make any inference to answer my question.

(Limiting the jurisdiction to US for now; there are many other jurisdictions where software patents would be invalid.)

Answer (score 1):

There are many many patents with the term "value-at-risk" in the tile or body. From google patents  -

The oldest one

> System and method for determination of incremental value at risk for
>   securities … EP US JP AU CA [US5819237A](https://patents.google.com/patent/US5819237A/en?q=%22value%20at%20risk%22&country=US&status=GRANT&sort=old) Mark B. Garman Financial
>   Engineering Associates, Inc. filed 1996-02-13

The most recent

> [US10277525B2](https://patents.google.com/patent/US10277525B2/en?q=%22value%20at%20risk%22&country=US&status=GRANT&sort=new) Method and apparatus for disaggregated overlays via application
>   services profiles Abstract Example embodiments of the present
>   invention relate to a method, a system, and a computer program product
>   for creating a dynamically composed compute node. The method includes
>   receiving an application characteristic and generating an
>   infrastructure allocation request according to the application
>   characteristic. The infrastructure allocation request then may be
>   forwarded to a management system associated with a disaggregated
>   infrastructure.

What google patents sees as the most relevant

> System and method for determining value at risk of a financial
>   portfolio US [US6085175A](https://patents.google.com/patent/US6085175A/en?q=%22value+at+risk%22&country=US&status=GRANT) Leon G. Gugel Axiom Software
>   Laboratories, Inc. Priority 1998-07-02 • Filed 1998-07-02 • Granted
>   2000-07-04 • Published 2000-07-04

Since we do not know the text book method you are talking about we can't compare your plans to the many issued patents in the U.S.

Comment: I appreciate the effort to search for and document a range of applicable patents to illustrate your point. +1